# How to change profile picture in wordpress?

Tags: profiles

In wordpress, how can I change the profile picture of administrator or the users added. I didn't find any option to upload your profile picture from your PC. I know it is possible if I use Buddypress plugin in my wordpress. Is there any way to change the profile picture without this plugin?

Answer (score 9):

### Default

WordPress uses [Gravatar](http://en.support.wordpress.com/avatars/), you can find more information about it [here](http://en.support.wordpress.com/avatars/).

> On WordPress.com, we use [Gravatar](http://en.support.wordpress.com/avatars/gravatars/) to associate an avatar with a user’s account. If you’ve set up a [Gravatar](http://en.support.wordpress.com/avatars/gravatars/), it will be displayed when you post to the forums or comment on a blog, and it may also appear if your blog is featured on a tag page.

### Custom - Backend

If you manually want to add images for your users, there are plenty plugins available to use:

1. [User Avatar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-avatar/)
2. [Simple Local Avatars](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-local-avatars/)
3. [Add Local Avatars](http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-local-avatar/)

### Custom - Frontend

You could use [Front-End Users](http://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-users/), this plugin supports the [User Avatar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-avatar/) plugin.
This topic is being discussed [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-user-avatar-how-to-integrate-with-front-end-upload).

Comment: Hello Mike, Its not a good solution for me If I use Gravatar, I have to attach picture with their email for each n every user. I want solution for my site specific.

Comment: I edited my answer for you :-) you can use a plugin to add the wanted functionality

Comment: All the mentioned plugin uses a back-end profile page image upload area. If we need a front-end solution, what can be then?

Comment: And another edit for you ;-)

Comment: Besides the above solutions, there is also the Profile Builder plugin that supports avatars http://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/